# Can´t figure out why selenium doesn´t open my website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.firefox.service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

firefox_bin = "/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox"
firefoxdriver_bin = "/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/geckodriver"

options = selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.binary_location = firefox_bin


service = selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service(executable_path=firefox_bin)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
browser.get("https://univirtus.uninter.com/ava/web/#/")
sleep(3)

ru = browser.find_element(By.ID, "ru")
ru.send_keys("login_example")
```

Tried to make a bot that opens a website a login in automatically to spare time. Tried for Firefox my main browser, but I only get errors from Firefox.bin and etc. In this case the browser opens but not the website, and doesn´t open my profile when I put the directory as well

> OS = Ubuntu Linux 22.04 LTS

Comment: /snap/bin/firefox /usr/bin/geckodriver are where I would expect your bin files on Ubuntu. Maybe check they are in the right place?

Comment: Yes, they are, but i doesn´t work

Comment: try/catch driver initialization and the get() so you can include the full exception(s) in your question.